# Functions of the template classes

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<class T>
void func1() {
    T.func2();
}
```

If I am sure that all possible classes will have the function `func2`, what should I do to get this code work?

When I tried this it says

> Error   C2228   left of '.getType' must have class/struct/union

Comment: `T` is a type not an object! If `func2` is a static method, you can call it via `T::func2()`

Comment: i mean forget about templates and take this example `struct MyClass { void func2(); };` how would you call the method `func2` ?

Comment: Thanks, I understand my problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to differenciate, if func2 shall be a static or a member function of your templated classes; static functions are addressed via scope resolution (`::`), for member functions, you need a concrete instance you most probably would pass as parameter:

```
template <class T>
void funcS()
{
    T::staticFunc();
}

template <class T>
void funcM(T& t)  // or T* t (pre C++11) / ::std::shared_ptr<T> t (since C++11)
{
    t.memberFunc(); // or t->... if using pointer
}
```

(Side note: raw pointers are not disallowed with C++11, as might appear from my comment, only not recommended any more...)

Comment: You should never be passing pointers around (they don't indicate ownership semantics and this is not an internal safe method were the semantics are known).

Comment: @LokiAstari they do : they should always mean "I don't own the object I'm pointing to".

Comment: @Quentin: The problem with pointers is that is not clear. If you don't own the pointer you should be using `std::unique_ptr` and moving it.

Comment: @LokiAstari I'm confused. if you have a `std::unique_ptr` to an object, you own it by definition. Same with a `std::shared_ptr`, but you share the ownership. But if all you have is a pointer, someone else is owning it, not you. That is, of course, assuming you follow the "no owning raw pointer" rule.

Comment: @Quentin: **NO**. If you have a pointer you **don't** know the ownership. That's why you we have smart pointers. You use `unique_ptr` to indicate a single point of ownership that can be transferred. You use `shared_ptr` to indicate shared ownership. RAW pointers have no ownership semantics (which is why there usage (outside a controlled interface) is so rare in modern C++). If you want somebody else to own the object you should be passing a reference.

Comment: @Quentin: Never heard of the `no owning raw pointer rule`. The problem this (if it exists) is a rule of thumb which the compiler is unable to enforce. This is why so much work is going into Stroustrup's new GSL; which contains wrappers for pointer to indicate they are non owning pointers (they are pointers and thus nullable but it is illegal to delete them).

Comment: @LokiAstari I've read this rule first from [Herb Sutter](https://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/) ("Smart pointers: No delete"). I see where we diverged : I've internalized that raw pointers and references are **always** non-owners. When this rule is followed, pointers can be used and passed around without a problem (references aren't always enough, for example when you need to rebind them). IIRC the GSL wrapper is mainly to ensure null-initialization, not hide the raw pointer per se.

Comment: @Quentin: Rebinding is a red herring as its parameter. No the GSL is to allow semantics to be enforced by the compiler onto the pointer that can not be done with RAW pointers. Basically it allows the compiler to detect incorrect usage and thus prevent errors (which can't be done on RAW pointers because there are no ownership semantics for pointers at the language level (which is why you don't see them in modern C++).

Comment: Thanks for contribution - updated my answer appropriately.